# sharedWithUsersId not returning up to date user ids

Tags: 2013, rest

I don't understand the response for the API call:

```
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeURL('/docs/Test.docx')/ListItemAllFields/SharedWithUsersId
```

I upload a `Test.docx` document and share it with two users.

The above rest call returns something like

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://.../_api/$metadata#Collection(Edm.Int31)",
  "value": [
    6,
    15
  ]
}
```

I open the share dialog in the web interface and share the document with one more user. I then get a response like:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://.../_api/$metadata#Collection(Edm.Int31)",
  "value": [
    6,
    15,
    25    <---- User just added
  ]
}
```

as expected.

I open the share dialog again and **remove** the user that I just added. After this the response is **still**:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://.../_api/$metadata#Collection(Edm.Int31)",
  "value": [
    6,
    15,
    25    <---- User has been removed from share list
  ]
}
```

It looks like `SharedWithUsersId` contains all user ids that the document has *ever* been shared with.

Is this the expected behavior?! Is this particular endpoint documented somewhere?